# XCode 6 crash when I select "Create a new Xcode Project"

Tags: xcode, crash

I run Xcode 6.0.1, and I click the "Create a new Xcode Project" and just wait or click the mouse(on the blank area), the Xcode crashed. I am sure I did nothing to it and it's OK in Xcode 5.

The OS verison is 10.9.5, the Xcode version is 6.0.1. I have upgrade to `iCloud Drive` on my iPhone 5.

I have tried to disable version control or reinstall the Xcode/CLT, but unfortunately Xcode crash as well.

The error log is:

```
Process:         Xcode [1196]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         6.0.1 (6528)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6528000000000000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [166]
Responsible:     Xcode [1196]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-30 15:43:04.618 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  4D5B9754-5C7C-0147-7A2D-D0DD7771F098


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A317
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEPlugins/IDEPlugins-6244/iCloudSupport/iCloudController.m:797
Details:  Assertion failed: _workspace.finishedLoading
Object:   <iCloudController: 0x7f8ab972cbc0>
Method:   -_findContainerNamesToWipe
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8ab34174d0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
```

Comment: I have tried to restart OS and install the Xcode form App Store and remove Xcode with CMM2, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Xcode config file might help. Try running this command.

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem but it was with adding a new file.  I ran this command via the terminal:

sudo find / -name '.DS_Store' -exec rm {} \;

Then I added the files I created previously as new before the crash.  Upon build I received an error say it could find a file in the info.plist

I went to XCode => Perferences => Derived Data => Clicked on gray arrow listed after path location which opened it up. => closed XCode => Deleted everything the Derived Data folder => Opened the project again in XCode and it built.

Hope that helps.